# MongoClient insert_one works while mongoengine connect doesn't (unautherized)

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I try to insert document using mongoengine interface AFTER authentication, but still gets denied. This doesn't happen using MongoClient...

This is the mongoengine try to insert one document:

```
In [1]: from mongoengine import connect

In [2]: db = connect(host='localhost', port=27017, username='root', password='pass')

In [3]: db.local.col.insert_one({'a':1})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationFailure                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-55a23806fbb1> in <module>
----> 1 db.local.col.insert_one({'a':1})

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in insert_one(self, document, bypass_document_validation, session)
    696         write_concern = self._write_concern_for(session)
    697         return InsertOneResult(
--> 698             self._insert(document,
    699                          write_concern=write_concern,
    700                          bypass_doc_val=bypass_document_validation,

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in _insert(self, docs, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val, session)
    611         """Internal insert helper."""
    612         if isinstance(docs, abc.Mapping):
--> 613             return self._insert_one(
    614                 docs, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id,
    615                 bypass_doc_val, session)

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in _insert_one(self, doc, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val, session)
    600             _check_write_command_response(result)
    601
--> 602         self.__database.client._retryable_write(
    603             acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
    604

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in _retryable_write(self, retryable, func, session)
   1496         """Internal retryable write helper."""
   1497         with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
-> 1498             return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
   1499
   1500     def _handle_getlasterror(self, address, error_msg):

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in _retry_with_session(self, retryable, func, session, bulk)
   1382         retryable = (retryable and self.retry_writes
   1383                      and session and not session.in_transaction)
-> 1384         return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
   1385
   1386     def _retry_internal(self, retryable, func, session, bulk):

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in _retry_internal(self, retryable, func, session, bulk)
   1414                             raise last_error
   1415                         retryable = False
-> 1416                     return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
   1417             except ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
   1418                 if is_retrying():

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in _insert_command(session, sock_info, retryable_write)
    588                 command['bypassDocumentValidation'] = True
    589
--> 590             result = sock_info.command(
    591                 self.__database.name,
    592                 command,

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py in command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok, read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, check_keys, read_concern, write_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation, session, client, retryable_write, publish_events, user_fields, exhaust_allowed)
    681             self._raise_if_not_writable(unacknowledged)
    682         try:
--> 683             return command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok,
    684                            self.is_mongos, read_preference, codec_options,
    685                            session, client, check, allowable_errors,

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py in command(sock_info, dbname, spec, slave_ok, is_mongos, read_preference, codec_options, session, client, check, allowable_errors, address, check_keys, listeners, max_bson_size, read_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation, compression_ctx, use_op_m
sg, unacknowledged, user_fields, exhaust_allowed)
    157                 client._process_response(response_doc, session)
    158             if check:
--> 159                 helpers._check_command_response(
    160                     response_doc, sock_info.max_wire_version, None,
    161                     allowable_errors,

~/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py in _check_command_response(response, max_wire_version, msg, allowable_errors, parse_write_concern_error)
    165
    166             msg = msg or "%s"
--> 167             raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response,
    168                                    max_wire_version)
    169

OperationFailure: command insert requires authentication, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'command insert requires authentication', 'code': 13, 'codeName': 'Unauthorized'}
```

which fails, but the MongoClient works for some reason:

```
In [4]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [5]: col = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017, username='root', password='pass')

In [6]: col.local.col.insert_one({'a':1})
Out[6]: <pymongo.results.InsertOneResult at 0x7ff2a347a8c0>
```

Comment: Did you authenticate to the correct database? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 Perhaps the defaults are different.

Comment: What is `local` in those?

Comment: `db` is the client, `local` is the db name, `col` is the collection